# ZeroMQ Messaging Queues

Tags: message-queue, zeromq, messaging

I am working for a while with ZeroMQ. I read already some whitepapers and a lot from the guide, but one question remained open to me:

Lets say we use PUB-SUB.
Where or on which system are the messaging queues? On the publisher system side, on the subscriber system side or something in between?

Sorry for the maybe stupid question.
This picture is from the Broker vs. Brokerless whitepaper.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *Where or on which system are the messaging queues?*

The concept of the Zen-of-Zero, as built-into ZeroMQ uses smart and right enough approaches, on a case by case principle.

### There cases, where there are no-Queues, as you know them, at all :

for example, the **`inproc://`** transport-class has no Queue, as one may know them, as there are just memory-regions, across which the messages are put and read-from. The whole magic thus appears inside the special component - the **`Context()`**-instance. There the message-memory-mapping takes place. The `inproc://` case is a special case, where no I/O-thread(s) are needed at all, as the whole process is purely memory-mapping based and the `Context()`-instance manipulates its internal states, so as to emulate both an externally provided abstraction of the Queue-alike behaviour and also the internal "Queue"-management.

### Others, similarly, operate **`localhost`**-located internal Queue(s) endpoints :

for obvious reason, as the ZeroMQ is a broker-less system, there is no "central"-place and all the functionality is spread across the participating ( coordinated and cooperating ) nodes.

Either one of the Queue-ends reside inside the `Context()`-instances, one in the one-side's `localhost`-itself, the other in the "remote"-host located `Context()`-instance, as was declared and coordinated during building of the ZMTP/RFC-specified socket-archetype `.bind()`/`.connect()` construction. Since a positive acknowledgement was made for such a ZMTP-specific-socket, the Queue-abstraction ( implemented in a distributed-system-manner ) holds till such socket does not get `.close()`-ed or the `Context()`-instance did not get forcefully or by a chance `.term()`-ed.

For these reasons, the proper ***capacity* sizings** are needed, as the messages may reside inside the `Context()`-operated memory before it gets transported across the `{ network | ipc-channel }`-mediated connection ( on the `.send()`-side ) or before being `.recv()`-ed ( from inside the remote `Context()`-instance ) by the remote application-code for any further use of the message-payload data ( a Zero-copy message-data management is possible, yet not all use-cases indeed use this mode for avoiding replicated memory-allocations and data-transfer costs ).

Comment: @muella91 Pleasure to hear that. All the best in your further research work!

Answer (score 1):

Every zeromq socket has both send and recv queues (The limits are set via high water mark).

In the case of a brokerless PUB/SUB the messages could be queued on the sender or the receiver.

Example:

- If there is network congestion the sender may queue on its send queue
- If the receiver is consuming messages slower than they arrive they will be queued on the receiver recv queue

If the queues reach the high water mark the messages will be lost.

Comment: With all respect, the presented claim "***Every* ZeroMQ socket has both send and recv queues**" is **not correct**. There are socket-archetypes, like PUSH or PUB that **do not have recv-traffic and thus do not have a recv-queue, similarly PULL and SUB socket-archetypes do not have any send-traffic at all, thus do not have any send-queues.

Comment: pub/sub sockets have both send and recv queues. The sub socket has to send the subscription message(s) to the publisher, the user may not have access to these message unless they use xpub/xsub but the queues are definitely there.

Comment: Negative, sir. The original SUB-archetype has been delivered ALL messages, irrespective of the Topic-filtering and only upon having collected each and every message, the SUB-side local-processing took place so as to decide, which messages will get dropped ( on no matching Topic-filtering subscription, kept locally on the SUB-side ). Next, after some re-engineering decisions took place, the Topic-filtering process was "moved" onto the PUB-side, yet the archetype uses this on a ZMTP-protocol level as an internal protocol-(in-band)-telemetry exchange, so there is no sending Queue even in the v4.+